# How to capture the MessageID of an Outlook email that was just sent using VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook

I generate an email in VBA and send it. I have a class which includes the send event for that email so I am able to tell if the email has been sent.
I need to capture the MessageID property once the email has been sent.

I thought I could use the class variable and get the properties from it but it seems there is no message ID. I assume the messageID does not come until a later event.

Is there some other event I can hook onto which occurs after the messageID is generated?
I thought unload could work but it does not seem to.
I thought about using the outmail object after the send but I guess the outmail object becomes nothing after it is sent which is why I am trying to do this in the class.

Code in my class event:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents oMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Public WithEvents oOutlookApp As Outlook.Application

Public Sub oMailItem_Send(Cancel As Boolean)

    'Find what version number from previous query of base review table --- ActiveVersion
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Cancel = True
        EmailSent = False
    Else
        EmailSent = True
        MsgBox oMailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001E")
    End If
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the event actually fire when the mail is sent?  What exactly happens when you send a mail?

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the [ItemAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Items.ItemAdd) event of the `Items` class for the `Sent Items` folder, it is fired when one or more items are added to the specified collection.

```
Public WithEvents myOlItems As Outlook.Items 

Public Sub Initialize_handler()  
 Set myOlItems = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items  
End Sub  

Private Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)  
 MsgBox Item.Subject 
End Sub
```

Comment: I actually tried this item event and i still get a blank messageid unfortunately. I can get the entryid but that is not unique if it moves.

Answer (score 0):

When Outlook sends a message in the cached mode, it hands the message to the Exchange server and moves the message to the local Sent Items folder. Exchange Server then actually sends the messages and moves it to the server-side Sent Items folder. The message now has the message id, but Outlook assumes the messages are the same (to an end user) and does not sync the two (just an optimization trick).

If you access the cached message, message id won't be present - you need to open its online  version, You can do that using using Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi, use `MAPI_NO_CACHE` bit when calling `IMsgStore::OpenEntry`) or [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am its author - any language). Note that if you use `Items.ItemAdd` event in the cached mode to open the online version of the message, you can get an error if the server is still sending/moving the message. You really need to use `Items.ItemAdd` event on the online folder.
In case of Outlook Object Mode alone, the only thing you can do is turn the cached mode off and use the `Items.ItemAdd` event. In case of Redemption, you can leave the cached mode on and use something similar to the script below:

```
Public WithEvents myItems As Redemption.RDOItems 

MAPI_NO_CACHE = &H0200
PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001F"

set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set sentItemsFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
'reopen in the online mode
set items = Session.GetFolderFromID(sentItemsFolder.EntryID, , MAPI_NO_CACHE).Items

Private Sub myItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)  
 MsgBox Item.Fields(PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID)
End Sub
```

Comment: Very thorough answer however I have one additional question as we are not able to use third party software like redemption (which solves all of my issues from my reading) that hasnt gone through government compliance. I use the itemadd event and the entryID shows up but the messageID is still blank. Could that be due to the cached exchange issue where you are saying it is still sending/moving?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am saying - the cached version of the message will not have the message id. Only the online version will. If you cannot use Extended MAPI or Redemption, turning the cached mode off is your only workaround.